# Using Javascript to determine if app is installed on iOS Device

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, iphone, deep-linking

Using Javascript (and regular React) I need to determine if an iOS device has an email app installed. I will have the user's email from a form. If they have an app installed I will direct them to the corresponding email app deep link with a button.

Example: Email - jon@gmail.com, the deep link is googlegmail://

After doing a whole bunch of research I do not see any straightforward way of doing this. There are old Iframe hacks or testing the userAgent but nothing has worked so far. I have also read it's a privacy issue too.

I have tried this iFrame hack:

```
async function checkGmailInstalled() {
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  iframe.src = emailClient.iosLink;
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    iframe.onload = () => {
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
      console.log('Gmail app launched');
      resolve();
    };
    iframe.onerror = () => {
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
      console.log('Failed to launch Gmail app');
      resolve();
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
      console.log('Timed out waiting for Gmail app');
      resolve();
    }, 3000); // Wait for 3 seconds even if the iframe doesn't load
  });
}
```

And the attempt for using the userAgent:

```
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
const isGmailAppInstalled = /mobile/i.test(userAgent) && /gmail/i.test(userAgent);
```

and the log for userAgent which does not contain gmail:

```
[Log] useragent – "mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 16_0_2 like mac os x) applewebkit/605.1.15 (khtml, like gecko) version/16.0 mobile/15e148 safari/604.1"
```

And I tried this as well...

```
 // Check if the `mailto:` protocol is supported, thus app is supported
      const isMailToSupported = () => {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = 'mailto:test@example.com';
        return typeof a.protocol !== 'undefined' && a.protocol === 'mailto:';
      };
```

Comment: You can use the navigator.platform property and check if it returns 'iPhone' or 'iPad' to determine if the user is on an iOS device. Once you've determined that the user is on an iOS device, you can check if the device has any email app installed by trying to open a URL with a mailto: link.
I can add in the answer an example of the code you can use

Comment: @LorenzoCastagno, @user3840170 I have the check for iOS all set already. A problem with a `mailto:` link is that it does open up an app but it also opens up a draft to create an email. Not super ideal. 

Also to complicate using deep links, there can be a scenario where the user has say a Gmail account but is using the Mail app for it. I would first need to check if the Mail app was installed `message://` then `googlegmail://`